# How can i update a observable in custom bindings?

Tags: knockout.js

I am having a binding handler with simple logic inside where i will update the observable so it will update itself in view .

This i a sample case where everything works as expected

**My View :**

```
<input data-bind="value: name" />
<hr/>
<div data-bind="fadeInText: name"></div>
```

**Code :**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInText = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element,valueAccessor);//text becoz its binded to div
    } 
};
```

Here I'm trying to do something like this(below) and i am stuck here `updating a observable`

**My view :**

```
<input data-bind="value: name" />
<hr/>
<input type="text" data-bind="fadeInText: name" />
<div data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data)"></div>
```

**Code:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInText = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element,valueAccessor);
    $(element).change(function () {
            value($(element).fadeInText('get'));
        });
    } 
};
```

In this given scenario there are two textboxes when i update a value in textbox-1 then textbox-2 value is getting updated .

But when i try to update textbox-2 value nothing gets updated i feel so close but for now i can't crack this up .

Checked chrome console i see `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` but `fadeInText` is present in binding

**Update :**

I tried `allBindingsAccessor().fadeInText()` i get the old value everytime not the new entered one .

Fiddler provided [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/SmkpZ/467/)

There is something with same way done but its working [**fiddler here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/9z26k1qb/2/).

Any help on this one is great .

Comment: Have you tried updating the observable using `value(element.value);`? See http://jsfiddle.net/SmkpZ/469/

Comment: `yeah` looking like that's the piece i'm missing here `haim770` . i tried element.val() , $(element).val() but how you came up with element.value ? anywhere is that documented .

Comment: Since the `element` parameter is the native `HTMLInputElement` being passed (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), it provides the `value` property. Yet, you have to realize that you're re-binding the `change` event everytime the observable changes and that will cause multiple evaluation of the handler. You better move the `change` binding to the binding-handler `init` function.

Comment: Also, `value(this.value);` would work as well (since jQuery automatically applies the element as function context of callback).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to wrap the `value` binding, you must call its `init` as well:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeInText = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element,valueAccessor, allBindings);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {  
       var value = valueAccessor();
       ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element,valueAccessor);
    } 
};
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/SmkpZ/470/).

Here's why: your `fadeInText` update handler is called automatically when the `name` observable changes - accessing it in the `update` handler registers it. So one half of the two-way binding — observable to input field — works.

For the other half of the two-way binding — input field to observable — you need to call the `init` handler of the `value` binding, because that is where `value` sets up the event handler for it to be notified when the input field changes.

As a rough rule of thumb, you use the `init` part of a custom binding for the code that changes the observable when the HTML element has changed (e.g. by attaching event handlers), and the `update` part to change the HTML element when the observable has changed.

Comment: I agree with you and `Haim770`  i need to do any sort of change work in `init` . +1 for the excellent tip .